# Spyder software shortcut query?

Tags: spyder

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select and copy the current line when the cursor blinks in Anaconda spyder software editor ?

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The default shortcut for this action is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>